# DW Design (PO and Invoices)

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse

I have to build a DW to store PO and Invoice data:

- An Invoice has a header and a list of items
- A PO has a header and a list of items.
- An invoice can be related to zero or more POs
- A PO can be related to one or more invoices.

How is the recommended way to design this in star schema?

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: Not yet... I want to check the best practices first...

Answer (score 4):

Designing a DW involves understanding multiple aspects before having a model.

1. What is the frequency of data refresh.
2. What is the volume of data.
3. Which columns need to be indexed. Also, which index will help you better.
4. The queries written on the tables. Are the queries aggregates? or are they straight select statements.
5. What is your history preservation strategy.
6. The data types of every column you need. You need to think about cross platform query executions...

So on and so forth..

You will need to deep dive into it. Just creating tables with FK will help now, but over the time when data volume increases it will be a bottleneck.

Comment: To answer your questions: Data is refereshed once a day, and volume isn't that big, total is couple of million rows for each (invoices and POs).  My problem is how to design the data warehouse: I currently went with this approach: I created two facts FactPO (which has all PO lines and headers) and another fact FactInvoice (which has all Invoices lines and headers).  I am connecting both with two tables: InvoicePOLineBrdige this connects the lines of Invoices to lines in POs and another table: InvoicePOHeaderBridge: This connects the PO headers to Invoice Headers.

Comment: Would recommend also considering your indexing strategy on the Fact tables.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in that you are modelling data, not process.

Star schemas are based on a business process, not an entity relationship.

What are you trying to model? What is the grain of the model?

I'll go out on a limb, and say that you're probably modelling sales. Have one fact: Sale. If you need order-specific information, consider whether it is part of an Order dimension, or if it should be carried as degenerate dimensions and/or measures in the Sale fact.

Comment: I am modeling supply chain data.  operations create a PO, and then we get invoices.  Sometimes the invoices are just created without a PO.

Comment: I think this advice will help you greatly:
http://www.kimballgroup.com/2007/10/design-tip-95-patterns-to-avoid-when-modeling-headerline-item-transactions/

Comment: Thank you Ron.  This is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a Invoice_Header_Fact and a Invoice_LineItem_Fact. (This can be denormalized and merged in one table too)
- Use Order_Key from Header Fact in LineItem Fact to associate it to lineitems
- Create a PO_Header_Fact and a PO_LineItem_Fact.
- Use PO_Key from Header Fact in LineItem Fact to associate it to lineitems
- Create a bridge/xref table to maintain many to many relationship between PO and Invoices.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Dimensional models don't have relationships between facts. Where necessary, drill across stars through conformed dimensions.